# For a blog: should I define CRUD functions for categories and tags in ArticlesController or create controllers of their own?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel beginner here. So as you can guess I am creating an blog where user can create an article under a category and have different tags.

I have defined plenty of routes for articles already.

```
public/article/{id}/show
public/article/{id}/delete
public/article/create
```

So if I define a CategoriesController and a TagsController, I'm going to have to to define all of these CRUD methods in it and the routes too as:

```
public/categories
public/categories/{id}/delete
public/categories/create
public/tags
public/tags/create
public/tags/delete
```

Should I move ahead and build it this way or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about an administration system, you need CRUD to maintain your tags table.

In a curated system, where tags are controlled, the process of adding tags involves finding existing tags, perhaps asynchronously.  You could utilize id's behind the scenes, assuming you have a relational database.

As people type some characters into the tagging portion of the UI, the system asynchronously finds a matching tag and displays it.  Once that has occurred, there is no reason not to use the tag ID, and in that case, having a full set of tag routes is useful, but is not essential unless you have curated tags.  For example, even if you want to use relational keys to store the relationship, you probably just need a search function which takes a tag string, searches for the matching tag, and returns that matching data.

In some systems, whatever tags are provided are added on the fly, but even in those cases, they are usually at least conformed.  For example, you might want to eliminate bad words, mixed case, punctuation etc.

In short, if you need to maintain a tag table, then you will want CRUD for tags.  If not, then adding tags, would just be part of the dataset that is operated on probably as part of the POST, when an article is created.

Also, just logically speaking, you shouldn't have a route for /public/article/{id}/create.  It should just be /public/article/create

Answer (score 0):

here are some good directions to look for

use RESTful Resource Controllers so you don't have to define each and every CRUD operation seperately. It would make your routes and controllers neat and clean. plus RESTful its a recommended nice way.

[RESTful Resource Controllers](http://RESTful%20Resource%20Controllers)

Another way is patterns. use good patterns for designing structure and behavior. here are some good reads. have a look

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/

http://shawnmc.cool/the-repository-pattern

https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns

one nice and common way is to use repository pattern. In repository pattern the repositories work in between models and controllers.

> "Repository commonly refers to a storage location, often for safety or
>   preservation." - Wikipedia

This would make your controllers and models simple and clean.